# How to move latest filename by date to another folder with .BAT?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

Hello i want to move files with latest filenames.

We have files that are created everynight.

Filenames are like this :

```
KOHe5_20160410.txt
LU5_20160410.txt
MOHe5_20160410.txt
```

and i want to move just those that are created that night.

I used this code first:

```
robocopy C:\SOURCE C:\OUTPUT KOHe5_*.txt /MOV /S /MAXAGE:1

robocopy C:\SOURCE C:\OUTPUT LU5_*.txt /MOV /S /MAXAGE:1

robocopy C:\SOURCE C:\OUTPUT MOHe5_*.txt /MOV /S /MAXAGE:1
```

But this is taking the created date on file. I want take the date on the filename and take the latest.

Any idea how ?

Comment: Are you using same-date, or date-before? The `date /t` command in batch will give you the current date as a string. You could `SET` that to a variable and use string slicing to get it in YYYYMMDD format.

Comment: But it's not date-aware. You have no way to do `date /t -minus 1d` or etc

Comment: ok so how would i do that? Can you please provide the full code. I just need to move the latest file based on the date in filename to another folder, nothing else

Comment: @AdamSmith ugly with pure batch, but possible. Easy with external tools (powershell, vba) Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+yesterdays+date)

Comment: @Stephan yes yes, it's *possible* of course, but not really feasible. I wish I'd taken the time to teach myself powershell better. Every time I poke my head in windows sysadmin stuff I think to myself "Powershell would probably make this easy."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how you get the files sorted by name and select the last one:

```
cd /d c:\source
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b /on KOHe5_*.txt') do set last=%%i
```

you then can copy, xcopy, robocopy or whatever `%last%`:

```
copy %last% c:\destination\*
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, can you please provide the full code as im completely new to this.

Comment: use the `move` command instead of `copy`? See `move /?` for help.